# How to design a model and its child django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, model

How to design a model in django for storing below JSON values in a single model

```
class Bus(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price=models.FloatField()
```

I need to accept below json to accept and store in same table 
if i can use ListField , then how it will be for connections

```
  {  
     "source": "delhi",
     "destination": "pune",
     "type": "Economy",
     "price":300.0,
     "Connections": [
                        {
                            "source": "lon",
                            "destination": "liverpool",
                            "type": "luxury",
                         },
                        {
                            "source": "banglur",
                            "destination": "cochin",
                            "type": "luxury",
                         }
                    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships).

```
from django.db import models

class Connection:
    source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Bus(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.FloatField()
    connections = models.ForeignKey(Connection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or [JsonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField).

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Bus(models.Model):
        source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        destination = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        price = models.FloatField()
        connections = JSONField()
```

Comment: this is not the solution , i need everything in one model

Comment: i know i can solve this with designing another model and make a foreign key relations, that's why i repeat my question with two times (JSON values in a single model,store in same table)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: DictField is part of Django Rest Framework serializer, not Django.

Comment: You're welcome, accept my answer if it helped you :)